# Slim app unable to execute single function from external .php script

Tags: php, api, slim-3

I've got a real head-scratcher here for you. I've been working on a Slim API for the last little while now. Within one of my routes I call a number of functions from an external .php script. For some reason all these functions work EXCEPT ONE...

I refer to the external script as recommended by Slim using `include('functions.php');` at the top of my route in question.

Within a route I make use of this `functions.php` script several times in a row. Get this, the `clone_source_directory()` function executes and returns as expected as well as the `update_db_config()`, `generate_virtual_host()`, and `restart_apache()` functions also perform as anticipated. For some reason `my_fancy_function()` always returns an error, regardless of naming, casing used, etc.

Why can I call my other functions which reside in the exact same script, but not `my_fancy_function()`?

The route itself works at it should, simply this function's execution isn't cooperating, here are my function calls:

```
$reply['cloneDir'] = clone_source_directory($ssh, $result['srcCompanyFolderName'], $result['srcPropertyFolderName'], $result['destCompanyFolderName'], $result['destPropertyFolderName']);
$reply['cloneDB'] = my_fancy_function($ssh, $result['srcCompanyFolderName'], $result['srcPropertyFolderName'], $result['destCompanyFolderName'], $result['destPropertyFolderName']); //<-- THIS ONE REFUSES TO WORK
$reply['updateDbConfig'] = update_db_config_file($ssh, $siteToClone->database_name, $result['destCompanyFolderName'], $result['destPropertyFolderName']);
$reply['createVirtualHost'] = generate_virtual_host($ssh, $server, $result['destCompanyFolderName'], $result['destPropertyFolderName']);
$reply['apacheSilentRestart'] = restart_apache($ssh, $server);
```

For simplicity sake I've reduce `my_fancy_function()` to simply return `true` upon execution:

```
function my_fancy_function() {
   return true;
}
```

All of this wouldn't be complete without a nice cryptic error message from Slim. So here it is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
        <title>Slim Application Error</title>
        <style>body{margin:0;padding:30px;font:12px/1.5 Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;}h1{margin:0;font-size:48px;font-weight:normal;line-height:48px;}strong{display:inline-block;width:65px;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Slim Application Error</h1>
        <p>The application could not run because of the following error:</p>
        <h2>Details</h2>
        <div>
            <strong>Type:</strong> Error
        </div>
        <div>
            <strong>Message:</strong> Call to undefined function my_fancy_function()
        </div>
        <div>
            <strong>File:</strong> /var/www/sites/marc/angus-api/routes/sites.php
        </div>
        <div>
            <strong>Line:</strong> 560
        </div>
        <h2>Trace</h2>
        <pre>#0 [internal function]: Closure-&gt;{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#1 /var/www/sites/marc/angus-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php(41): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#2 /var/www/sites/marc/angus-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(344): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse-&gt;__invoke(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#3 /var/www/sites/marc/angus-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(122): Slim\Route-&gt;__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#4 /var/www/sites/marc/angus-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(316): Slim\Route-&gt;callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#5 /var/www/sites/marc/angus-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(476): Slim\Route-&gt;run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#6 /var/www/sites/marc/angus-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(122): Slim\App-&gt;__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#7 /var/www/sites/marc/angus-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(370): Slim\App-&gt;callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#8 /var/www/sites/marc/angus-api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(295): Slim\App-&gt;process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#9 /var/www/sites/marc/angus-api/index.php(20): Slim\App-&gt;run()
#10 {main}</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions why I can't seem to create myself a new function in `functions.php` that I can execute from within my API route?

Comment: Is it really called `my_fancy_function` or have you changed it for SO? If so it could be a different error all together. cloneDB does not really suit `my_fancy_function`?

Comment: Yeah, `my_fancy_function` is just a product of testing, hahaha. That's not the issue though. Slim just can't see to run it, regardless of naming.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. This code looks fine.

Comment: Can you double check its really the error `Call to undefined function`, got a feeling its something else as what your saying about it being in the same file as the others, it seems improbable.

Comment: Yeah providing an mvce is not really an option... This application is way too big. The problem in question is as explained above, it's really just as simple as why this function won't execute while the others in the same script do.

Comment: "Call to undefined function my_fancy_function". Let's try `echo function_exists('my_fancy_function');`

Comment: It could be as simple as a typo on the functon name :/

Comment: As recommended by @DanielO. I've added `return '{"functionExists":"'.function_exists('my_fancy_function').'"}';`
My output is as follow:
`{"functionExists":""}`

Comment: Try to rename the functiom. Try to load the file 'functions.php' via composer.json. https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

Comment: So I've gone ahead and delete the function in `functions.php` and the function call from my route.
I've since gone ahead and recreated them with a new name and no params required. The error I'm seeing now is in regards to the number of parameters requires.
It seems to me like the server is using some old cached version of 'functions.php' but I'm not using slim-cache or anything else of the type...